# display image with fancybox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying display an image using `fancybox`, but not working.

My code:

```
<div id="example2" style="display:none;">
<a id="single_image" href="#"><img src="style/images/promocional-01.jpg" alt=""/></a> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#single_image").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if you have a display:none on the div.. what do you expect to be the clickable area?

Comment: yes... on the load of the page.. on the load the fancybox show up

Comment: according to the docs, you can add this code instead doing it in js:  <a data-fancybox data-src="#example2" href="javascript:;" >Open image</a>

Comment: its a link.. i need this: when the page load, show the fancybox popup.. automatically

Answer (score 3):

this works.. but how can i put in `responsive` ??

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
     'width': '800px',
    'height': '286px',
    'autoScale': true,
    'transitionIn': 'fade',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
    'type': 'image',
    'href': 'style/images/banner.jpg'
 });
```

works fine in normal screen, but responsive not working.

up...

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues:

1. You need to add the `fancybox` click event
2. You forgot to add a proper `href`.
3. In this instance, you do not need the `img` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a#single_image").fancybox().click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<div id="example2" style="display:none;">
    <a id="single_image" href="http://i.imgur.com/uN7Y8gw.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: well... `display:none` it is not working and the fancybox shows this message: `The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.`

Answer (score 1):

The link to the slider should not be in the div with

```
style="display:none;"
```

so

```
  <a id="single_image" href="big_version_of_image.jpg">
  <img src="style/images/smaller_version_of_img.jpg" alt=""/>
  </a>
```

should work.

here is a link with a working pen:

https://codepen.io/faw/pen/KmZdbK